# Can I run custom .sh files while building docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to use docker with custom `nginx` module. So I have to download nginx, extract, rebuild and install it. It's a lot of work.

Can I implement this logic in `.sh` file and ask docker to execute this file while building image. I tried:

```
ADD nginx/nginx-build.sh /home/fbelov/nginx-build.sh 
RUN ["/home/fbelov/nginx-build.sh"]
```

but it doesn't work

```
 ---> Running in e90e561c3b80
/bin/sh: 1: /home/fbelov/nginx-build.sh: not found
INFO[0001] The command [/bin/sh -c /home/fbelov/nginx-build.sh] returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Comment: Please share the error message...

Comment: i do that sort of thing a lot.  on https://github.com/tacodata/postgresdev/blob/master/Dockerfile you can see a download of postgres, and a subsequent compile/install of it, including creating users and whatnot.  like @AdrianMouat says, an error message please :-)

Comment: @Greg thanks, looks like it worked for me. But what's the benefit of using a lot of `RUN`/`WORKDIR` commands inside `Dockerfile` file? Why I can't implement it as `.sh` file as Docker to execute it?

Comment: Looks like the file isn't there. Can you double check that your paths are correct and /home/fbelov exists?

Comment: you can.  are you *sure* you have a directory fbelov *inside* the container?  maybe a simple RUN adduser before the ADD command would fix it (or a mkdir -p /home/fbelov)

Comment: BTW it is pretty common to see Dockerfiles run several commands in one line. Using sh files make things a lot more opaque is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your ADD did not work correctly, as in execution it can not find the file. Check if the destination directory exist and try to use COPY instead of ADD.